# WebView2 blank page when publishing WinUI3 app through DevOps pipeline due to 32-bit DLL file being included

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, winui-3, webview2, dotnetcorecli

I have created a WinUI3 application that uses the Microsoft.Web.WebView2 package (version 1.0.2045.28). When I build or publish the app locally from Visual Studio the app works as expected. When I publish it from an Azure DevOps pipeline however, I only get a blank white page whenever I launch the WebView from within the app.

I have determined that the problem is likely caused by the Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll file in my app directory being a 32 bit DLL instead of 64 bit when publishing the app via the DevOps pipeline, despite the fact that I have set X64 as the target platform. (Swapping it out afterwards solves the problem).

How can I make sure the DevOps pipeline builds the app with the 64 bit version of WebView2?

Here's the relevant parts from my pipeline:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: 'MySolution/MySolution.sln'
  project: 'MySolution/MyApp/MyApp.csproj'
  buildPlatform: 'X64'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: '$(project)'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory) -p:Platform=$(buildPlatform) -p:PublishSingleFile=false --self-contained true'
    zipAfterPublish: true
    modifyOutputPath: false
```

I also tried to add -r win-x64 to the arguments but it made no difference.

Comment: When you define the buildPlatform: X64 and use it in the dotnet publish task, will it work as expected?  Can you check if the platform define in the MySolution.sln is X64?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I believe I already have the platform specified in the arguments in the Yaml above? -p:Platform=$(buildPlatform).

Comment: Glad to know that you have found the method to solve the issue. You can accept your answer. This will be helpful to other users who has the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a workaround. The root of the problem seems to be that becuase I'm referencing both Microsoft.Identity.Client (which has WebView2 as a dependency) and Microsoft.Web.WebView2, there is a conflict between the packages:
https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/5689

To workaround the issue above I have the following lines in my .csproj file, otherwise it won't compile:

```
    <ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>false</ErrorOnDuplicatePublishOutputFiles>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Client" Version="4.57.0" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Web.WebView2" Version="1.0.2088.41" Aliases="webview2" />
```

...the DLL that ends up in my output folder seems to be a 32 bit version built for .Net core 3.1, probably from the webview2 dependency for Microsoft.Identity.Client.

I discovered that the correct version of the DLL can be found in the obj folder after a build, so I managed to add theese lines to my .csproj file to copy it to the output directory after a build or publish:

```
 <Target Name="PostBuild" AfterTargets="PostBuildEvent">
    <Exec Command="copy &quot;$(ProjectDir)obj\$(Platform)\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetFramework)\$(RuntimeIdentifier)\MsixContent\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll&quot; &quot;$(TargetDir)&quot;" />
  </Target>
  <Target Name="PostPublish" AfterTargets="Publish">
    <Exec Command="copy &quot;$(ProjectDir)obj\$(Platform)\$(ConfigurationName)\$(TargetFramework)\$(RuntimeIdentifier)\MsixContent\Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Core.dll&quot; &quot;$(PublishDir)&quot;" />
  </Target>
```

Not a solution to the actual problem, but with this workaround my app now works as expected.